# Displaying current page stats for RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, paging, radgrid

So, I'm trying to display something like "Displaying 1-20 of 100" using a RadGrid control. I put the following code in the RadGrid1_PageIndexChanged event:

```
int showingRowsFrom = ((e.NewPageIndex + 1) * rgResults.PageSize) - rgResults.PageSize + 1;
int showingRowsTo;

if ((e.NewPageIndex + 1) == rgResults.PageCount)
{
    showingRowsTo = GridSource.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
}
else
{
    showingRowsTo = (e.NewPageIndex + 1) * rgResults.PageSize;
}

string rowCount = string.Format("Displaying {0}-{1} of {2}", showingRowsFrom, showingRowsTo, GridSource.Tables[0].Rows.Count);
lblResultsCountBottom.Text = lblResultsCountTop.Text = rowCount;
```

Unfortunately, it looks like this doesn't do a full postback and the label doesn't end up getting updated. How can I go about doing this? I tried doing it client side and had problems with this, too. It says $find is undefined.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var grid = $find("<%=rgResults.ClientID%>");
    var mtv = grid.get_masterTableView();
    var pageIndex = mtv.get_currentPageIndex();
    alert(pageIndex);
});
```

Here's the radgrid code:

```
<radG:RadGrid ID="rgResults" runat="server" AllowMultiRowSelection="True" AllowPaging="True"
        AllowSorting="True" EnableAJAX="False" GridLines="None" OnItemCommand="rgResults_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="rgResults_ItemDataBound"
        PageSize="20"
        Skin="Default" Width="100%" OnPageIndexChanged="rgResults_PageIndexChanged" OnSortCommand="rgResults_SortCommand" OnInit="rgResults_Init" OnPreRender="rgResults_PreRender">
    <ClientSettings ApplyStylesOnClient="True">
    </ClientSettings>
    <ItemStyle CssClass="griditemtext" />
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridheadertext" />
    <FooterStyle CssClass="gridfootertext" />
    <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="gridalternetitemtext" />
    <PagerStyle CssClass="gridpagertext" Mode="NumericPages" />
    <CommandItemStyle CssClass="gridcommandtext" />
    <SelectedItemStyle CssClass="gridselecteditemtext" />
    <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        DataKeyNames="Article Number" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" CommandItemDisplay="None" Font-Overline="False"
        Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" GridLines="Both">
        <ExpandCollapseColumn Visible="False">
            <HeaderStyle Width="19px" />
        </ExpandCollapseColumn>
        <RowIndicatorColumn Visible="False">
            <HeaderStyle Width="20px" />
        </RowIndicatorColumn>
        <PagerStyle Mode="NumericPages" />
        <Columns>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</radG:RadGrid>
```

I won't post the code for all of the columns, because they're all done the same way, but here's the gist :-p

```
var hyperLinkColumn = new GridHyperLinkColumn
{
    DataNavigateUrlFields = new[] { "TransactionID" },
    Target = "_blank",
    DataNavigateUrlFormatString = @"~/w1/SearchResultDetail.aspx?id={0}",
    DataTextField = "Article Number",
    HeaderText = "Article Number",
    SortExpression = "Article Number",
    UniqueName = "ArticleNumber"
};
rgResults.Columns.Add(hyperLinkColumn);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems I have found an answer to my question. I've tried tons of different things, but it looks like the one that did it was maybe referencing the wrong version.

I was using:

Telerik.WebControls.GridBoundColumn

instead of

Telerik.Web.UI.GridBoundColumn

for example.

Once I changed this around, the $find, and other ajax stuff started working. Maybe I was using the non-AJAX RadGrid before, which would explain it, I suppose...

But anyways, thanks to @rdmptn for all of your help!

Answer (score 3):

If the label is not updated you have AJAX so you need to make sure to include the label in the partial postback response. If it is not in an UpdatePanel already, wrap it in one. If its UpdateMode is Always (the default value) things should work immediately. If you set it to Conditional you would need to call its Update() method. You may also want to set its RenderMode to Inline to avoid breaking your layout.

On the client-side approach - use the Sys.Application.Load event because MS AJAX script cotnrols are not available before that, hence the $find() issue. For example:

```
function alertMe() {
  var grid = $find("<%=rgResults.ClientID%>");
    var mtv = grid.get_masterTableView();
    var pageIndex = mtv.get_currentPageIndex();
    alert(pageIndex);

Sys.Application.remove_load(alertMe);
}
Sys.Application.add_load(alertMe);
```

Comment: This didn't end up helping in this situation, but good information for sure! I realized I needed to drag a script manager onto the page for the $find function to work. Unfortunately, my grid variable is still coming up null, but it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: I don't even know how you managed to get anything related to MS AJAX to work without a script manager in the first place. With my sample the only things that can prevent the grid variable from getting the proper reference are a JavaScript error somewhere else, or the rgResults grid being invisible (i.e., having Visible=false). If neither is the case - post the full code that will show the problem so we can have a crack at it.

Comment: I didn't have anything AJAX on the page except for the find. I'm new to this project, and I know it's a little quirky. With your code sample, I was able to figure out the issue (when 2 AJAX functions weren't working, it became a little more clear :-p). It seems like one of the issues may be that I need to use a RadScriptManager? But that seems to be causing all kinds of problems. With the code you supplied, with a standard script manager, the $find returns null. It is getting into the alertMe() function.

Comment: try adding a timeout in the function so that $find() and the subsequent code are executed later. There shouldn't be problems with this, I have used it too many times.

Comment: Well, it's not that. I set a 30 second timeout, waited around for it to hit the break point, which it did, and still returned null. I guess it has to do with how the radgrid is rendered? I don't know. I assume I need to be using a RadScriptManager, so I'll have to figure out how to go about doing that.

Comment: It is not necessary to use a RadScriptManager, it is an asp:ScriptManager with some goodies on top, so this should not make a difference. $find() returning null means a Sys.Component with the provided ID does not exist on the page. Make sure the ID is correct and it matches the rendering of the control (it should with my snippet if the grid is in the same NamingContainer). Remove ClientIDMode=Static if you use it. POst your code.

Comment: First off, thanks for sticking with me :) I don't see a ClientIDMode=Static anywhere. Which code would be useful? The radgrid code? I'll edit my question with that for now, and add more if that's not what you meant.

Comment: Make sure you follow this when creating your grids programmatically: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-programmatic-creation.html.
Also, post your AJAX setup because I believe this is the root cause - nested AJAX settings and/or UpdatePanels, most likely. Confirm there are no script errors.